# how to fire jQuery togglePanels manually

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I am using the jQuery and HTML shown on this fiddle and for the life of me am not able to manually fire individual tabs.

http://jsfiddle.net/DkHyd/

```
$("h3").toggleClass("ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-state-default ui-corner-bottom").find(".ui-icon").toggleClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-e ui-icon-triangle-1-s").end().next().slideToggle();
```

The above jQuery will toggle all of the elements, but if I reference an individual in this manner:
    $("#ToggleHeader").etc
it will not work.

I'd love some help and hopefully an explanation why this isn't working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you tried doesn't work because the selector `$("h3")` matches every `h3` on the page, so the operations that follow are applied to all of them. The second solution you tried didn't work because the `h3` elements in your html code do not have any ids.

Add an id to each element, and then select the header using the id selector `$("#ToggleHeader")`

```
<h3 id="ToggleHeader"><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
```

etc..

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear; on each H3 I have an ID and I want to fire the toggle by the ID. So for example:
$("#Receive").etc
I would rather not have to use an index since I also use jQuery cookies to choose which panels remain open on page load.

Comment: there are no ids in the jsfiddle example though, did you forget to add them to the h3 elements?

Comment: I'd like to go on the record and say that I did have the right idea, but for some idiotic reason, I had spaces in my IDs so of course it wasn't working.
I'm at a loss for words, but thank you for the answer :) I will give you the credit.

Comment: it happens to the best of us.